# How to find dependencies of a specific ruby gem version?

Tags: api, rubygems

I'd like to find dependency information of Ruby gems. Based on the [documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api) this will return a list of dependencies of the latest *rails* gem:

```
https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/rails.xml
```

But how do I get the meta information of a specific version, e.g. *rails 3.0.0* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently it's not possible.

It seems that the only way is to call:

```
https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
```

But this returns the dependencies for all versions. Well, better than nothing.